# Flex: How to Tell if the Current App is Running on a Simulator or a Real Device or Browser

Tags: ios, apache-flex, ios-simulator

I have a Flex library, that is used in my Flex mobile or web app. If I run the app on iPad Simulator, `Capabilities.os` gives me `Mac OS 10.7.5`, so how can I tell (from the Flex library) if the current app is running on a simulator or real device or browser?

The one I'm using is:

```
    public static function isSimulator():Boolean
    {
        return Capabilities.version.indexOf("IOS") >= 0 && Capabilities.os.indexOf("Mac OS") >= 0;
    }
```

But I am not so confident with this.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?  The simulator will return "MAC OS etc..." while running on an actual device will return 'iOS etc.."

Comment: It seems there should be more robust solution. but I just cannot find.  Only "Mac OS" won't work.  A regular web application will also return it, so I added `Capabilities.version.indexOf("IOS")`, but still I feel it's awkward.

Comment: PErhaps you should clarify your question.  You asked about how to tell the difference between running in a simulator and running on a real device; you didn't ask anything about running in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

See [`Capabilities#isDebugger`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#isDebugger). I don't believe you can tell which device is being simulated, but it will tell you if you are in the Debugger or not.